# Download and Parsing JSON issue with android studio

Tags: android, json, http, stock

I am new to android studio and I was wondering what I am doing wrong. I am using the alpha vantage api to get stock data for a personal project. The issue is that when I create the http request I only download around 111 days worth of data; however, when I use the link that I provide my code, the webpage populates with many more days (multiple years) of data. Is there something wrong with the way Im querying my request?

Here is my AsyncTask I call

```
 public class JsonResponseTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {                                                       
 protected void onPreExecute(){                                                                                            
     super.onPreExecute();                                                                                                 

 }                                                                                                                         
 protected String doInBackground(String... params){                                                                        

     HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;                                                                           
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;                                                                                 
     InputStream inputStream = null;                                                                                       
     StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;                                                                                     
     try{                                                                                                                  
         URL url = new URL(params[0]);                                                                                     
         httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                                                     
         httpURLConnection.connect();                                                                                      
         if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {                                                                  

             inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();                                                             
             bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));                                      
             stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                                                                            
             String line = "";                                                                                             
             while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                                                          
                 stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");                                                                         
                 Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line); //a lot of logs                                                         
             }                                                                                                             
         }                                                                                                                 
         else{                                                                                                             
             Log.e("mainActivity", "Error response: " + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());                              
         }                                                                                                                 
         return stringBuffer.toString();                                                                                   
     } catch(MalformedURLException e){                                                                                     
         e.printStackTrace();                                                                                              
     } catch(IOException e){                                                                                               
         e.printStackTrace();                                                                                              
     } finally{                                                                                                            


            parseJson(stringBuffer.toString(), params[1]);                                                                                                                                         


     }                                                                                                                     
     return null;                                                                                                          
 }
```

Here's the parseJson method it calls after the string buffer is finished

```
 static List<String> parseJson(String response, String FeatureType){                                                                                                              
 String currFeature = null;                                                                                                                                                   
 ArrayList<String> ListofIndicators = new ArrayList<>();                                                                                                                      
 //this the day iterator it will loop through the weekdays to pull technical indicators specified in json                                                                     
 //                                                                                                                                                                           
 Calendar calander = Calendar.getInstance();                                                                                                                                  
 String date = null;                                                                                                                                                          





 try{                                                                                                                                                                         
     JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);                                                                                                                      
     JSONObject jsonResults = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("Technical Analysis: " + FeatureType);                                                                               
     //I know that there is a large amount of info but I only want to go back to till.... like 2002                                                                           
     //so I'll only make a limited number of iterations                                                                                                                       
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonResults.length(); i++) {                                                                                                                         
         JSONObject currFeatureTimeStep = jsonResults;                                                                                                                        

         while(calander.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY || calander.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {                                            
             //go back one day                                                                                                                                                
             calander.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);                                                                                                                                 
         }                                                                                                                                                                    
         //generate date string                                                                                                                                               
         date = String.valueOf(calander.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "-" + String.valueOf(calander.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + "-" + String.valueOf(calander.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 



         currFeature = currFeatureTimeStep.getString(date);                                                                                                                   

         calander.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);                                                                                                                                     

         ListofIndicators.add(currFeature);                                                                                                                                   

     }                                                                                                                                                                        
 } catch (JSONException e){                                                                                                                                                   
     Log.e("MainActivity", "Error parsing JSON response", e);                                                                                                                 
 }                                                                                                                                                                            
 return ListofIndicators;                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? I've ran debug mode and I check the value that stringBuffer.toString() passes to parseJson and it only contains a few months worth of data not years worth that I see when I use the same link in the browser? I feel as if my bufferedReader is too fast? maybe it is reading it too fast and the api can't keep up so it reads null before it loads the next set of data?

Comment: Can you provide the link you are using?

Comment: need API url so i can check json data sample

Comment: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SMA&symbol=MSFT&interval=weekly&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=demo

Comment: heres a link with a demo theres a ton of data here but I only get. few :(

Comment: The only difference between that link and mine is that I have an api key instead of demo in the url